# Is there a command that clears the Y-variables?

Tags: ti-basic

I have a command that essentially functions like clearing the memory, but doesn't wipe programs and sets the settings I like. I found out that while it does its job well, it doesn't seem to clear the equations in the `Y=` menu. Is there a command or another way to achieve this?

```
PROGRAM:CLEAR
:MATHPRINT
:Normal
...
:DiagnosticOn
:ClrDraw
:Clear Entries
:ClrAllLists
:SetUpEditor
:ClrHome
:"
```

Comment: I found what I now believe to be the best answer to this question using graph database variables. If you're still looking for a solution check out the edit I made to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a similar note to TimTech, `Delvar` can be used to reset the value of a variable.

```
DelVar Y1
```

The benefit of this is that multiple `DelVar` calls can be chained without a line break.

```
DelVar Y1DelVar Y2Disp "Done
```

---

A non-programmatic way of clearing a calculator is to use the key sequence <kbd>2nd</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>. Unfortunately, this also clears programs.

This method will clear all RAM on the calculator, so use it with caution.

---

I found a better programmatic way of clearing the Y-VARS. This method also resets all other graph settings to their default value. In your case, this seems to be a desirable side-effect. Unfortunately, it requires a little bit of set up and occupies one of the Graph Database variables (119 Bytes). Because this variable can be kept archived, this does not consume any RAM.

## Setup

1. Manually clear **All** `Y-VARS`, including parametric, polar and sequence variables.
2. Manually Reset **All** graph window settings to their default

   - `ZStandard`
   - `RectGC`
   - `CoordOn`
   - `GridOff`
   - `AxesOn`
   - `LabelOff`
   - `ExprOn`
3. Store current setting in a Graph Database variable

   - `StoreGDB GDB1` entered with key strokes: <kbd>2nd</kbd><kbd>PRGM</kbd><kbd>◄</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>VARS</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>
4. Archive `GDB1`

   - `Archive GDB1` entered with keystrokes: <kbd>2nd</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>VARS</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

## Use in Program

To use this archived variable in a program, you must unarchive it, recall its contents, and finally archive the variable again. This is accomplished by the following code block.

```
UnArchive GDB1  
RecallGDB GDB1  
Archive GDB1
```

If you're using a TI-83 calculator, you need to skip the steps involving archiving because the TI-83 does not support flash memory. The TI-83 Plus and above work fine, however.

Comment: Actually, I forgot about this. This would save 1 byte over mine because of the chaining. By the way, don't try `2nd + 7 1 2` unless you want to clear the user-accessible RAM portion of your calculator...

Comment: @Timtech yeah... that'll clear every thing... I'll add a warning to my answer. On that note, make this program: `AsmPrgrm:AA` and run it with `Asm(prgrmCLEAR` to clear every thing.

Comment: Cool! I probably won't try it, though ;)

Comment: @dohaqatar7 Also is there somewhere I can find RecallGBD? Because I had to look in the catalog for it.

Comment: @JeffreyLin It is under the `STO` sub-menu of of the draw menu. Keystrokes: `2nd PRGM ◄ 4`

Comment: A few typos; shouldn't all of the GBD be GDB?

Answer (score 2):

No command, but you can do `"->Y1` or `DelVar Y1` to clear `Y1`, and similarly for the others.